# How to make drop-down values to be easily authorable content in CQ

Tags: aem, dropdownbox

I was trying to understand how can we make drop-down values in dialog box easily authorable?

Answer (score 0):

Select lists in dialogs can load their options dynamically from anywhere, so long as they are provided as an array of values in JSON format ([from the docs](http://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.form.Selection)):

```
[
    {
        value: "pink",
        text: "Pink",
        qtip: "Real Pink"
    }
]
```

So one solution would be to:

1. Create a new template that would allow an editor to add/remove values from a list — make this editable for content authors as per any other content (e.g. using the page properties, or components that you can drag onto that template).
2. Create a Servlet that will parse those values & output them in the expected JSON.
3. Register that servlet, e.g. via a path (`/bin/selectvalues`).
4. Using the `cqinclude` xtype to load in your values:

i.e.

```
<select
    type="select"
    xtype="selection"
    options="/bin/selectvalues"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a drop-in solution for this, take a look at http://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/generic-lists.html. This supports easily authorable lists of name/value pairs which can be used (without writing additional code) in:

- Classic UI Dialogs
- Touch UI Dialogs
- Touch UI Asset Metadata Editor